# Question about notation of partial derivatives.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have found this and got a little confused, I know the notation but never seen anything like this before: 
$$\begin{align}x(u,v)&=u+v\\y(u,v)&=\sin(u+v)\\
\det&\left(\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right).\end{align}$$ What am I differentiating right here? is it $x_u, y_u, x_v, y_v$ or $x_u,x_v,y_u,y_v$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#Examples

Comment: It means the determinant of the derivative of the function $f:\mathbf{R}^2 \to \mathbf{R}^2$ given by $f(u, v) = (x, y)$ (with $x$ and $y$ as stated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is:$$\left|\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}& \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}& \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\end{matrix} \right|= \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}-\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}
$$

Answer (score 2):

As I have seen it, the matrix $$\left(\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right)$$
is the Jacobian (or differential) matrix of the function $f(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v))$, so its determinant would be the Jacobian determinant.

Edit: more explicitly,
$$\left(\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right) = \begin{pmatrix} x_u & x_v \\ y_u & y_v \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right|=\left|\begin{matrix} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \end{matrix}\right|=\left|\begin{matrix} x_u\ x_v \\ y_u  \ y_v \end{matrix}\right|$$

This is known as the Jacobian.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matrix. The $(i,j)$-entry of $$\frac{\partial (f_1,...,f_n)}{\partial (x_1,...,x_m)}$$is $\partial f_i/\partial x_j$.